# How to download Debian testing i386 without GUI?

Tags: debian, command-line, system-installation, gui, download

I had an old computer in which I want to install Debian, but it is so old that I thought that I should install Debian without any desktop environment. I tried out their latest stable version, which is outdated. How do I download or install Debian testing without GUI? My old computer does not have any Internet connection, thus netinst is not an option for me. I tried to find it on their official site, but it's too complicated for me to find it.

I am open to unstable version too.

#### edit

I installed as GAD3R said it in VirtualBox, but I can't update in it. I had uploaded the screenshot bellow[image][image]

I had uploaded image because I can't paste the text.

Comment: toggle "Desktop environment".  https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/ch06s03.html.en#di-install-software

Comment: I can't imagine what  `debian-testing-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso` (645M) is going to leave you with, so you probably want the DVD sets (or larger, but only the CDs and DVDs are available as straightforward download images).

Comment: @sourcejedi So do you mean that  testing/unstable Debian version without GUI is not available?

Comment: This seems a very strange set of requirements.  I think you're really constraining yourself a lot by not using the current Ubuntu release.  (Or, use jessie-backports to upgrade the specific software you need, using apt-offline to download the package files for the offline machine).

Comment: @sourcejedi i am noob.Thus i didn't know what is jessie-backports or apt-offline

Comment: That doesn't explain why you're not using Ubuntu :-P.

Comment: It's true that there's no Debian images that skip GUI packages, for either stable or unstable.  So you're going to have to accept some dead weight, that you download but never install.  Note that "Ubuntu Server" (same release schedule as Ubuntu Desktop) images do not include a GUI... Ubuntu are more modern, they don't provide full image sets, you will have to use apt-offline if you want anything that didn't fit in the 682M image.  So I guess Debian is good if you wouldn't be able to use apt-offline.

Answer (score 2):

You should download the  [debian-stretch-DI-rc4-i386-xfce-CD-1.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/stretch_di_rc4/i386/iso-cd/) image (647M).

During the system install the network configuration will fail , skip it .

You will be invited to select your mirror choose **No**

Only select the **Standard system utilities** from the software selection:

**software selection**:

```
[ ]Debian desktop environnement
[ ]...Xfce
[X]Standard system utilities
```

Finally install Grub on your hard drive then reboot your system.

To get a usable operating system you should configure your network and your `sources.list`

**Network configuration:**

Refer to [Setting up an Ethernet Interface](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Setting_up_an_Ethernet_Interface) to setup your ethernet interface .

edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` as follow:

```
 auto eth0
 allow-hotplug eth0
 iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Note: you can not use the `net-tools` command such as `ifconfig` ... to manage your network , the minimal install come with the  `iproute` tool , you should use it as alternative.

Use `ip link` to get your ethernet interface name and replace it on the `interfaces` conf file.

Bring up your interface and get an IP through dhcp:

```
ip link set eth0 up
dhclient eth0
```

**sources.list configuration**

Edit your sources.list:

```
apt edit-sources
```

There is a sample `sources.list` with the `non-free` component :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

If you don't nedd the `non-free` software you can remove it.

Comment the others lines ( cdrom , urls) on your `sources.list`

Comment: I installed it in vertualbox but,I cant update in it.I had uploded the screenshot above

Comment: @linuxman i have edit my answer