# Debian testing installtion guide

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I am using Ubuntu mate but I want to switch over the Debian mate or Debian lxde (testing). Thus i need to know following points

- Will my Debian testing will remain testing for all the time?

suppose i had install Debian testing buster.after few years it became the the stable.So will my Debian also become stable?Will i still receive testing updates?

- I want to install Debian mate(or Lxde) testing but i didn't find it on there site.should i download the entire dvd-1 of Debian testing.iso or should i do netinst?Or should I download all 3 dvds of Debian testing?I tried to search live cds but they all were stable(outdated)
- Is debian testing is not good or unstable?does it crash or does it have so many bugs?
- Is it compatible for my latop?here is the output of `lscpu` command

  ```
  smit@Smit-Aspire-5742:~$ lscpu
  Architecture:          x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
  CPU(s):                4
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
  Thread(s) per core:    2
  Core(s) per socket:    2
  Socket(s):             1
  NUMA node(s):          1
  Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
  CPU family:            6
  Model:                 37
  Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 370  @ 2.40GHz
  Stepping:              5
  CPU MHz:               933.000
  CPU max MHz:           2399.0000
  CPU min MHz:           933.0000
  BogoMIPS:              4787.75
  Virtualization:        VT-x
  L1d cache:             32K
  L1i cache:             32K
  L2 cache:              256K
  L3 cache:              3072K
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
  Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sepmtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good noplxtopologynonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm arat
  ```

Comment: Your question has several questions, and may get closed for being too broad. I would also suggest that you avoid opinion-based questions, such as: "Is debian testing is not good or unstable?does it crash or does it have so many bugs"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Will my Debian testing will remain testing for all the time?

   The file controlling updates is /etc/apt/sources.list.
   If the word used in the deb lines is testing (as opposed to stretch):

   ```
   deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing non-free contrib main
   ```

   then, yes, your debian will remain in testing. If you use stretch, the system will remain in the (now stable version stretch) and will receive only security updates.

   ```
   deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch non-free contrib main
   ```

   Testing and stretch are exactly equal now that debian is in freeze, later the packages in testing will start to get new versions and the two will grow different each passing day.

   But that is not a problem as you can change that word in the future and update to a new version.

   There is only a hard limit, once you move your system forward, there is no known way to move back (other than re-installing an older version).
2. I want to install Debian mate(or Lxde) testing …

   Probably xfce would be a better option, small like lxde but looks better.
   No, it is not a gnome or kde based option but can run programs from both/either.
3. … but i didn't find it on there site.

   Here you go (torrent links to gnome, kde, cinnamon, mate, lxde or xfce), and assuming you need an amd64 version (others are available at the same site):

   ```
   https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/bt-hybrid/
   ```

   Those are live versions that you dd to a pen drive, boot from it, and, if all works reasonably well, use the same pen-drive to install to the local disk.

You do know how to use a bittorrent link, don't you?

4. should i download the entire dvd-1 of Debian testing.iso or should i do netinst?

   Netinst is probably the most correct solution, but I already gave you the live torrent links.
5. Or should I download all 3 dvds of Debian testing?

   Oh, please no, do not download all 3, that is a very big waste of bandwidth.
6. I tried to search live cds but they all were stable(outdated)

   Now you have the live versions for debian 9

Comment: I have downloaded the Debian stretch.can i turn it into Debian testing by changing `/etc/apt/sources.list` file ?

Comment: Yes, after you have executed an `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` (or you have updated and applied updates in synaptic) you can change that word and apply again both commands (or synaptic). Understand that that will get you on testing, now should be very stable as it has just been released. But in a couple of months, testing may get into some update trouble which you will have to endure. Also, testing does not receive security updates (too much change to also have those).

Answer (score 0):

> Will my Debian testing will remain testing for all the time?

Debian [**buster**](https://wiki.debian.org/fr/DebianBuster) is now the testing release

> Buster is the development codename for Debian 10.
>
> It is the current testing distribution.

---

> I want to install Debian mate(or Lxde) testing but i didn't find it on there site.should i download the entire dvd-1 of Debian testing.iso or should i do netinst?Or should I download all 3 dvds of Debian testing?I tried to search live cds but they all were stable(outdated)

You can install the base system through the netinstall or using the xfce iso following the steps described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370758/153195) , then you can install the [LXDE desktop](https://packages.debian.org/buster/lxde) or the [mate desktop](https://packages.debian.org/source/buster/mate-desktop).

---

> Is it compatible for my laptop?

Yes it is compatible.

Comment: The iso you are linking to is an RC4 (release candiadte 4) of stretch, not the present distribution.

Comment: Also, the cpu the user have is a x86-64, you are linking to an i386 (32 bit) iso.

Comment: @Arrow the linked answer only to install debian without a GUI from an XFCE iso .